# Is there a connection between compactness and the Hilbert basis theorem?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was just talking with a few friends and we noticed something interesting. Namely, a straightforward corollary of the Hilbert Basis Theorem is:

> If $R$ is noetherian and $V \subset R^n$ is defined as the zero set of some (possibly infinite) collection $\{f_\alpha\}$ of polynomials in $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $V$ is the zero set of some finite set of polynomials.

This had a striking resemblance to the definition of compactness:

> A topological space $X$ is compact if every cover by a collection of open sets $\{U_\alpha \} $ has a finite subcollection.

My question is: is there a deeper significance to this similarity? Is "noetherian" some sort of analog of compactness?

Answer (score 3):

They are related.  A topological space is called *Noetherian* if every open subset is compact in the induced topology.

Let's not consider zero sets of polynomials and instead consider the Zariski topology on the prime spectrum of a ring $S$.  When $R$ is an algebraically closed field, and $S = R[T_1, ... , T_n]$, everything I'm writing corresponds directly to a statement about zero sets of polynomials.

Let  $X$ be the topological space $\textrm{Spec}(S)$.  This is the space of prime ideals of $S$ whose closed sets are of the form $V(I) = \{ \mathfrak p \in X : I \subseteq \mathfrak p\}$ for an ideal $I$ of $S$.  Assume $S$ is a Noetherian ring (for example, $S = R[T_1, ... , T_n]$). Then one can show that $X$ is a Noetherian topological space.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $S$ generated by elements $s_1, s_2, ... \in S$.  Let $I_n = \langle s_1, ... , s_n \rangle$.  The inclusion $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq I$ induces a descending chain of closed sets $V(I_1) \supseteq V(I_2) \supseteq \cdots \supseteq V(I)$.

Already we know that $I_n = I$ for some $n$, since $S$ is a Noetherian ring.  But let's directly use the property that $X$ is a Noetherian space to get a similar result.  The complements $X \setminus V(I_1) \subseteq X \setminus V(I_2) \subseteq \cdots$ form an open cover of $X \setminus V(I)$, and since $X \setminus V(I)$ is compact, there is a finite subcover, i.e. $X \setminus V(I_n) = X \setminus V(I)$ for some $n$.

Then $V(I_n) = V(I)$.  Actually, this doesn't tell you that $I_n = I$, or even that the zero set of $s_1, ... , s_n$ is the same as the zero set of $I$ if $S = R[T_1, ... , T_n]$ (unless $R$ is an algebraically closed field).  It does, however, tell you that $\sqrt{I_n} = \sqrt{I}$.